# Stubed Unit of Work method with Moq doesn't return the expected integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, .net-core, xunit2

I have a project created using Asp.Net Core, but I have a problem with unit testing one part of my controller's action, I use [xUnit.net(2.2.0-beta2-build3300)](http://xunit.github.io/) for testing and [Moq(4.6.25-alpha)](https://github.com/moq/moq4) for mocking, and [FluentAssertions(4.13.0)](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/FluentAssertions) and [GenFu(1.1.1)](https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu) to help me with my tests, I have a Unit of Work class (note that I cut it down to what's relevant to my question):

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{

    private readonly WebForDbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(WebForDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

     private IContactRepository _contactRepository;

     public IContactRepository ContactRepository
    {
        get
        {

            if (this._contactRepository == null)
            {
                this._contactRepository = new ContactRepository(_context);
            }
            return _contactRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

In my ContactRepository I have:

```
public class ContactRepository:IContactRepository
{
    private WebForDbContext _context;

    public ContactRepository(WebForDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public Task<int> AddNewContactAsync(Contact contact)
    {
        _context.Contacts.Add(contact);
        return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I inject the Unit of Work to my controller, my action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ContactViewModel contactViewModel)
  {
       var contactWioutJavascript = _webForMapper.ContactViewModelToContact(contactViewModel);

       int addContactResultWioutJavascript = await _uw.ContactRepository.AddNewContactAsync(contactWioutJavascript);

        if (addContactResultWioutJavascript > 0)
        {
            return View("Success");
        }
  }
```

What I want to do is to stub my `AddNewContactAsync` method to return an integer bigger than 0 (10 in this case), to inter the if clause, and test to see if the correct view is returned, my test class:

```
public class ContactControllerTests
{

 private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _uw;
 private Mock<IWebForMapper> _webForMapper;

    public ContactControllerTests()
    {
        _uw = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

        _webForMapper = new Mock<IWebForMapper>();
    }

   [Fact]
    public async Task Create_SouldReturnSuccessView_IfNewContactAdded()
    {
        var contactViewModel = A.New<ContactViewModel>();

        _webForMapper.Setup(s => s.ContactViewModelToContact(contactViewModel)).Returns(A.New<Contact>());

        _uw.Setup(u => u.ContactRepository.AddNewContactAsync(A.New<Contact>())).ReturnsAsync(10);

        var sut = new ContactController(_uw.Object, _webForMapper.Object);

        var result = (ViewResult)await sut.Create(contactViewModel);

        result.ViewName.Should().Be("Success");
    }
 }
```

But the method `AddNewContactAsync` returns 0, and my test doesn't enter the if condition that leads to `return View("Success")`, I know that the problem doesn't have to do with `ReturnAsync` because I've used it with other async methods and it works, also `_webForMapper` is stubbed correctly and map the view model to my domain model and `contactWioutJavascript` is populated with value, but when I debug the test and reach the `addContactResultWioutJavascript` line, it returns 0, no matter what I do.

The things I did, but didn't work:

I mocked the ContactRepository, and tried to stub that instead:

```
_contactRepository.Setup(c => c.AddNewContactAsync(A.New<Contact>())).ReturnsAsync(10);

_uw.SetupGet<IContactRepository>(u => u.ContactRepository).Returns(_contactRepository.Object);
```

I also found other questions:

[Moq Unit of Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956212/moq-unit-of-work)

[how to moq simple add function that uses Unit of Work and Repository Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154956/how-to-moq-simple-add-function-that-uses-unit-of-work-and-repository-pattern)

[Mocking UnitOfWork with Moq and EF 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809902/mocking-unitofwork-with-moq-and-ef-4-1)

But none of them helped, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: On a side note on the terminology  used, to avoid confusion: What you do there is not stubbing, its mocking (hence the name for this type of frameworks). Stubbing is a test implementation of the interface or base class, which usually means you need to implement all interface methods/properties where as in mock you can only configure/mock the one you need in your test

Comment: @Tseng According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27151309/1650277), _Stub - override methods to return hard-coded values, also referred to as state-based_, and I think this is what I did with `AddNewContactAsync` method, but I still might be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there.  Two things:

1. You do need to setup the `ContactRepository` property as Moq doesn't support "chaining" of setups.
2. Also, you need to use `It.IsAny<>()` instead of `A.New<>()`:

   ```
   _contactRepository.Setup(c => c.AddNewContactAsync(It.IsAny<Contact>())).ReturnsAsync(10);
   ```

   This says "match any `Contact` that is passed in".  When you used `A.New<>()`, you were saying "match the `Contact` instance that I just created with `A.New<>()`.  In effect, that will never match anything since you didn't save or use the return value of `A.New<>()`.